# Changed from a regular array to an arrayList

Tags: java

I have written code that printed out integers from a .dat file and moved them into a regular array and printed out the average and standard deviation. Now I want to switch from a regular array to an ArrayList. I have written the code below but doesn't seem run correctly.

.dat file includes these numbers: "51 52 55 57 58 61 62 63 66 66 66 70 72 73 74 75 75 77 77 78 79 81 82 84 86 87 88 91 94 97"

Thanks for the help!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;


public class gradeSorter{

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
{
DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("0.000");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("grades.dat"));
double average;
double deviation;
double sum = 0;
int number = 0;
ArrayList<Integer> element = new ArrayList<Integer>();


for (int count = 0; count < element.size(); count++)
{
while (scanner.hasNext())
{
element.add(scanner.nextInt());
number = element.get(count);
    for (int item : element){
        sum += number;
        System.out.println(number);
}

}

average = sum / element.size();

for (int i = 0; i < element.size(); i++)
{ 
sum += Math.pow((element.get(i) - average),2);

}


deviation = Math.sqrt((sum / (30-1)));




System.out.println("The average of these grades is : " + fmt.format(average));

System.out.println("The standard deviation of these grades is: " + fmt.format(deviation));  


}
}
}
}
```

UPDATE***

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;


public class gradeSorter{

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
{
DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("0.000");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("grades.dat"));
double average;
double deviation;
double sum = 0;
int number = 0;
int newnumber = 0;
ArrayList<Integer> element = new ArrayList<Integer>();



while (scanner.hasNextInt())
{
element.add(scanner.nextInt());


}
for (int item : element){
        sum += item;
        System.out.println(item);
}

average = sum / element.size();

for (int i = 0; i < element.size(); i++)
{ 
newnumber += Math.pow((element.get(i) - average),2);

}


deviation = Math.sqrt(newnumber / (element.size()));




System.out.println("The average of these grades is : " + fmt.format(average));

System.out.println("The standard deviation of these grades is: " + fmt.format(deviation));  


}
}
}
```

----jGRASP exec: java gradeSorter

51
52
55
57
58
61
62
63
66
66
66
70
72
73
74
75
75
77
77
78
79
81
82
84
86
87
88
91
94
97
The average of these grades is : 73.233
The standard deviation of these grades is: 12.288

----jGRASP: operation complete.

Comment: "doesn't seem run correctly", what do you mean? what doesn't work? error?

Comment: Some advice: use new iteration style (`for(X x : Xs)`), it's easier to read and less error prone and you have an hard-coded `30`, and last you have a potential divide by 0 error (empty data, but you should know that).

Comment: Is the title correct? I don't think that you have the data in an array. You have it in a file.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to match what you're asking.  If you want to go from an array primitive to a list: `Arrays#asList`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First Issue:**

Your `for` loop doesn't even run once, since `element.size()` is 0 initially, so the condition of loop will be false at the first iteration only:

```
for (int count = 0; count < element.size(); count++)
```

Just remove this loop. You don't need it. An `ArrayList` can grow dynamically. You don't need to bother about it's size.

**Second Issue:**

The `for` loop inside your `while` loop is doing the danger. It will accumulate the sum of all element, after adding each element. So, your `sum` won't be the sum of all elements of the list. It would be sum of the elements, added many times. You should move the *inner `for` loop* outside the `while`:

**Third Issue:**

You are using `scanner.hasNext()` and reading an int using `scanner.nextInt()`. You should only test for the element type, that you are reading. Use `scanner.hasNextInt()` to test for any available integer to read.

Well, there might be some more. But you should first solve these issues, and run the code to see what all parts did you got right.

---

In all, that part of your code should be modified to:

```
ArrayList<Integer> element = new ArrayList<Integer>();

// Remove the for loop from here

while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {  // Use scanner.hasNextInt()
    element.add(scanner.nextInt());
}

for (int item : element) {  // Moved this for loop outside the while loop
    sum += item;
}

System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: @Rohit Jain , I've updated my code with your suggestions above.

Comment: @James. `sum += number` should be `sum += item`

Comment: @James. And after you calculate the `average`, you need to re-initialize the `sum` to `0`.

Comment: @Rohit Jain, Updated again, I used number instead of sum for the deviation but the correct answer should be: 12.525. Also the numbers don't seem to print for some reason.

Comment: @James. `deviation = Math.sqrt((sum / (30-1)));` should be `deviation = Math.sqrt((number / (30-1)));` And what is `30-1` there?

Comment: @James. Please go through the code and see are you using the correct variables at all places. Most issue is because of use of different variable. Numbers are 0, because you are printing `number` in 1st for loop. You should print `item` instead.

Comment: @Rohit Jain, I've updated the code and numbers now print. I'm going to go over the deviation formula really quick and get back to you.

Comment: @James. Well, now you have used a new variable - `newnumber` in 2nd for loop. So, you should use it in deviation formula instead of `number`.

Comment: @Rohit Jain, I've updated the code and the deviation seems to printout correctly. Now what if I wanted to find the frequency of the numbers in a specific grade range? ex. 90-99 freq: 3 ... 80-89 freq - 6. Do you recommend I do an if statement with an improved for loop? What would be the best way going about?

Comment: @James. I think this a different question all together. You should post it as different question.

Comment: @RohitJain, Done... Thanks for your help. I will be posting a new question regarding this frequency issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove your for loop and things should run just fine. Just have this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
{
....
....
while (scanner.hasNext())
{
    number = scanner.nextInt();
    element.add(number);
    for (int item : element)
    {
        sum += number;
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
average = sum / element.size();
....
....
....
```

Also details of error you got would be useful.

Comment: I've updated the new code above, I have no errors at the moment.